# How do I only listen for DateTimePicker ValueChanged Event from user input

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I use the DateTimePicker Enter Event to set the Max Date to Yesterday's Date as I do not control if the user decides to leave the application open for days.

I also use the DateTimePicker ValueChanged Event to adjust my dialogues based on those selected dates.

The problem that I am facing is that every time I adjust the Max Date through the Enter Event, ValueChanged Event is also called and the value taken from the DateTimePicker is not the user value. Is there anything that I can do to only listen for the input change from the user?

The DateTimePicker CloseUp seems to help but only if the user uses the calendar to pick the date and not manually typing it in.

```
    private void dtpStartDate_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reports cannot be generated later than today.
        dtpStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1.0);
    }

    private void dtpStartDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate = dtpStartDate.Value.Date;
        DateTime endDate = dtpEndDate.Value.Date;

        dtp_CustomExclusionFrom.MinDate = startDate;
        dtp_CustomExclusionFrom.MaxDate = endDate;

        dtp_CustomExclusionTo.MinDate = startDate;
        dtp_CustomExclusionTo.MaxDate = endDate;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lv_CustomExclusionDates.Items)
        {
            String dateString = item.Text;
            DateTime exclusionDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

            if (exclusionDate < startDate ||
                exclusionDate > endDate)
            {
                lv_CustomExclusionDates.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect the ValueChanged event to only be fired by the user and not by the changes to MaxDate of the DateTimePicker.

Comment: unset the call to valuechanged before the maxdate changed, and then put it back?

Comment: Never did thought of that. I'll go try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Boolean field as a flag.

```
private bool isChangedFromCode = false;


private void dtpStartDate_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isChangedFromCode = true;
    // Reports cannot be generated later than today.
    dtpStartDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1.0);
    isChangedFromCode = false;
}

private void dtpStartDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(isChangedFromCode) { return; }
    // rest of the code here...
}
```

**Update**

Following our conversation in the comments - the code in your `dtpStartDate_Enter` event handler is not the one that fires the `ValueChanged` event, since it only changes the `MaxDate` property and not the `Value` property of the `DateTimePicker`.
You need to wrap whatever part of your code that's setting the `Value` property with that Boolean flag.
Infact, I would probably make it a method if you have multiple places in code that changes the value - and only use this method instead of directly setting the `Value` property:

```
private void SetDateTimePickerValue(DateTime value)
{
    isChangedFromCode = true;
    dtpStartDate.Value = value;
    isChangedFromCode = false;
}
```

Comment: I'll go try that out. But wouldn't Value Changed be fired after Enter finishes and not during?

Comment: the `ValueChanged` event will be fired when the value changes. If that happens because the code changes the value, it's just like when calling a method from another method - the execution of the event handler will happen and then the rest of the method that changed the value. However, I've noticed you've changed the `MaxDate` property and not the `Value` property in your code, so I think that something else must be going on there to fire the `ValueChanged` event. Anyway, a boolean flag surrounding whatever code that's changing the value of the datetimepicker will get the job done.

Comment: I mean the call to `dtpStartDate_ValueChanged` will only begin after `dtpStartDate_Enter` has finished, right? Based on my trials, `dtpStartDate_ValueChanged` is only called after `dtpStartDate_Enter` has finished and the Boolean flag has already been reset to false, so no luck for me.

Comment: No, it should't. It should be called when the `Value` property is changed. As I wrote, the code in your `enter` event handler doesn't change the `Value` property - some other code changes is. That's the code you should wrap with the flag. Search your code base for `dtpStartDate.Value =` to find that.

Comment: The strange thing is, there isn't any other code that modifies the value of the `dtpStartDate`. I always assume it to be user input so I only modify the max value.

Comment: With no code changes the `Value` property, the only thing that should raise the `valueChanged` event is user interaction. Look again. Perhaps in another class?